# is it possible to commit/rollback another procedures transaction in current procedure

Tags: sql-server, web-services, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, transactions

i have two questions

1.i have two stored procedures. is it possible to commit/rollback another procedure's transaction in my current procedure.

2.i have two webservices two services connected with same database or linked server database. one webservices gotsucceed it transactions. when moving to the second webservice some error got occured. if error occured i have to rollback the previous webservice transactions.? is it possible. if anyone explain related to banking transactions like ATM

is it possible?
how?
explain related to banking sector with little understandable coding.

Comment: If you have two questions, please ask them separately. For question 1, I suggest you tell us *why* you want to do that, because it isn't clear what you really need to do. Question 2 is very unclear, mainly because you didn't say what the error was, which component throws it, and when it occurs.

Comment: Regarding your first question, are you talking about nested stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, a commit must be issued from the same connection that the begin transaction statement was issued.
2. In this case you would first need to append the data tables with a "transaction" field or something similar that will uniquely identify each transaction.  If the second webservice needed to issue a rollback that touched the work of the first webservice, it would have to call a custom process would then issue deletes looking for the transaction identifier that you have built into the tables.  There's no built-in functionality of the db engine to accommodate this out of the box.